# jquery with previous and next button

Tags: jquery, tabs

i'm using jquery for tab, but i have to show 10 tab, is it any possibilities to show only 5 tab then show next button to move the tabs, like pagination moving,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/ check out the examples here http://www.seyfertdesign.com/jquery/ui.tabs.paging.html (the example right before the last one is what you need).